# iphone sqlite query optimization

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am currently using this sqlite query in my application. Two tables are used in this query.....

```
UPDATE table1 set visited = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.itemId) from 'table2' WHERE table2.itemId = table1.itemId AND table2.sessionId ='eyoge2avao');
```

It is working correct.... My problem is it is taking around 10 seconds to execute this query and retrieve the result..... Don't know what to do... Almost all other process are in right way.. So it seems the problem is with this query formation...

Plz someone help with how to optimize this query....

Regards,
Brian

Comment: Have you tried to query the SELECT statement in seperation? Just to see whether the SELECT is taking so long or the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes on the following (combinations of) fields:

- `table1.itemId`
  (This will speed up the DISTINCT clause, since the itemId will already be in the correct order).
- `table2.itemId`, `table2.sessionId`
  This will speed up the WHERE clause of your SELECT statement.

How many rows are there in these tables?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot friends...

Removing DISTINCT didn't help. It was still the same. 

But when I divided the query into two, it helped out :)...

Answer (score 0):

Aso try doing an [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) on your SELECT command to see if it gives you any helpful advice.